# Getting general SSL Engine problem while calling API in mule4

Tags: httprequest, httplistener, mule4

I am trying to call https API end point(implemented in mulesoft) using Request component(Mule component) from another flow. When i am calling from local machine it working fine. But when i deployed to Anypoint Exchange it is throwing General SSL engine problem. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Mule applications can be published to Anypoint Exchange for sharing in the organization, but they are not 'deployed' in Exchange, meaning they don't execute in Exchange. Are you deploying it to CloudHub? Or to an on prem Mule Runtime through Runtime Manager? What URL are you using? What certificate is exposed in the API implementation? Have you enabled Java SSL debug log to see the certificates? Please also attach the complete error message, with details including stack trace if present. Also the calling flow HTTP requester configuration, including if it is using a custom trust store.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use alternative way to reach end point with this SSL error. I guess url starts with https:// since it is throwing SSL exception. Grab this url and try to open it in some browser. It will tell you what is the reason for exception and is SSL certificate valid or not.

Work around it - make http config to ignore SSL certificate.
https://simpleflatservice.com/mule4/HowToIgnoreInsecureCertificates.html

After all it is yours (probably) service and you may trust it.

[image]